# windows batch file eq was unexpected at this time

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am writing a windows batch script that will Install a service. First, I need to find if the service already exists. If the service exists, it has to check the state. If the state is running, it has to stop and delete the service.

This is my code : test.bat. I am running this from command line.

```
for /F "tokens=3 delims=: " %%H in ('sc query "IBMLibertyProfile" ^| findstr "STATE" ') do (
  if /I "%%H" EQ "RUNNING" (
   sc stop "IBMLibertyProfile"
  )
)
```

I am getting error :

> C:>test1.bat EQ was unexpected at this time.
>
> C:>  if /I "%H" EQ "RUNNING" (

How to solve this error?

Comment: The comparison operator in an `if statement is `equ`, not `eq`. See `if /?` from the prompt.

Comment: Thanks that solved the issue. can you please modify the script to 
a. find if the service already exists. If the service exists, it has to check the state. If the state is running, it has to stop and delete the service.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
@rem If the service doesn't exist, exit.
@sc query IBMLibertyProfile > NUL 2>&1
@if %ERRORLEVEL% neq 0 @exit /b 0

@rem If the service is already stopped, delete it.
@sc query IBMLibertyProfile | findstr /s "STOPPED" > NUL 2>&1
@if %ERRORLEVEL% neq 0 @goto :DeleteService

@rem No matter it's state, tell it to stop.
@sc stop IBMLibertyProfile

@rem Wait for it to stop.
@set _WaitLoopCount=0
:StoppedWait
@if _WaitLoopCount equ 10 @goto :ServiceWaitTimeout
@timeout /t 3 > NUL 2>&1
@sc query IBMLibertyProfile | findstr /s "STOPPED" > NUL 2>&1
@if %ERRORLEVEL% neq 0 @goto :StoppedWait

@rem Delete the service and exit.
:DeleteService
@sc delete IBMLibertyProfile
@exit /b 0

:ServiceWaitTimeout
@echo Service failed to reach the STOPPED state. Reboot the computer and try again.
```

NOTE: If your service is not well behaved, the script might hang. I'll leave it to you to work out how to deal with sc delete failures.

Comment: Why do you have to `@` each command? You could `@echo off` at the beginning of the script. The `goto` loop can also be replaced by a `for /l` loop: `for /l %%G in (1,1,10) do ([\n]if %%G equ 10 goto :end [\n] rem the other command [\n])`

Comment: I am facing a peculiar behavior. When the service is already running and when someone tries to stop, delete and install the service again, the service gets installed again, but it fails to start. When I reboot the system, and start the service, it gets started. How to solve this start service issue without rebooting computer. I also added taskkill /f /PID <pid> to kill the process server.exe.

Comment: This is my code : 

for /F "tokens=3 delims=: " %%H in ('sc query %SERVICE_NAME% ^| findstr "STATE" ') do (
  if /I "%%H" EQU "RUNNING" (
   sc stop %SERVICE_NAME% >nul 2>&1
   timeout /t 30 /nobreak >nul 2>&1
  )
  sc delete %SERVICE_NAME% >nul 2>&1
)

for /f "tokens=2" %%a in ('tasklist^|find /i "server.exe"') do (taskkill.exe /f /pid %%a >nul 2>&1)

Comment: I have asked the question here :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47299637/windows-service-fails-to-start-when-the-service-is-already-running-using-windows

Comment: @SteveFest, I've worked on systems containing thousands of scripts with many layers of calls. `echo off` and `echo on` constrain composability and make debugging more difficult.  I prefer all my scripts to be usable from any script.  If I whack the '@' symbols and turn echo on for debugging in one script, I don't want a script that happens to be called, messing with my environment by turning it off.  Generally, I prefer to be more precise in my debugging anyway and remove '@' symbols only on specific lines, sometimes in multiple scripts.

Comment: @MalarKandasamy, what is your service start type?