# Windows Service fails to start when the service is already running using windows batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, windows-services

I am writing a windows batch script that will Install a service. If its already running, then I am stopping and deleting the service and then installing the service again.

I am facing a peculiar behavior. When the service is already running,  and when I am running the below batch file, the service gets installed again, but it fails to start. When I reboot the system, and start the service, it gets started.

How to solve this start service issue without rebooting computer. I also added taskkill /f /PID  to kill the process libertyserver.exe.

This is my code : test.bat. I am running test.bat from command line.

**test.bat:**

```
@echo off
setlocal

@echo off

set JAVA_SERVICE_EXE=libertyserver.exe
...
....
set SERVICE_DISPLAY_NAME="%LIBERTY_SERVICE_NAME%"
set SERVICE_DESCRIPTION="%LIBERTY_SERVICE_NAME%"

echo Stopping and Deleting existing services

for /F "tokens=3 delims=: " %%H in ('sc query %SERVICE_NAME% ^| findstr "STATE" ') do (
  if /I "%%H" EQU "RUNNING" (
   sc stop %SERVICE_NAME% >nul 2>&1
   timeout /t 30 /nobreak >nul 2>&1
  )

sc delete %SERVICE_NAME% >nul 2>&1
  timeout /t 30 /nobreak >nul 2>&1
)

for /f "tokens=2" %%a in ('tasklist^|find /i "libertyserver.exe"') do (taskkill.exe /f /pid %%a >nul 2>&1)

echo Installing liberty profile %SERVICE_NAME%

set INSTALL_SERVICE_COMMAND=%DAEMON_EXEC% //IS//%SERVICE_NAME% --Startup=manual --DisplayName=%SERVICE_DISPLAY_NAME% --Description=%SERVICE_DESCRIPTION% ++DependsOn=Tcpip --LogPath=%LOG_PATH% --StdOutput=auto --StdError=auto --StartMode=exe --StartPath=%SERVER_START_COMMAND_PATH% --StartImage=%SERVER_START_COMMAND% --StartParams=start#SIServer --StopMode=exe --StopPath=%SERVER_STOP_COMMAND_PATH% --StopImage=%SERVER_STOP_COMMAND% --StopParams=stop#SIServer
%INSTALL_SERVICE_COMMAND%

echo Installed liberty profile %SERVICE_NAME%
```

Comment: What are `...` and `....` supposed to do?

Comment: You should never use taskkill to kill a running service.  If your service is not stopping correctly, fix that.  If it is restarting because it is demand startable or because it is configured to be restarted when it goes down, then disable the service before stopping it.  Then wait for the SCM to tell you it has stopped.

Comment: What is `%DAEMON_EXEC%`?

Comment: You are failing to check the return codes from your sc commands.  Very bad practice.