# Stopping service in batch randomly does nothing

Tags: windows, batch-file, service

I'm having a strange error here.  I have a batch script that I use for deploying an application file and starting a service.  In that script I use some batch to check if the service is already running, and prompt the user to stop it if they want to.  That check and prompting is working, but every now and then when I attempt to use it to stop the service, it does nothing.  it just skips to the next step without any error.

Full Batch Script:

```
@echo off

set WILDFLY_DIR=path\to\wildfly\deploy\dir
set JBOSS_DIR=path\to\jboss\deploy\dir 
set EAR_DIR=path\to\ear\file\parent\dir
set SERVICE_WILDFLY=WildflyServiceName
set SERVICE_JBOSS=JBossServiceName
set SERVICE=
set DST=
set SRC=

goto :SEL_SERVER

:SEL_SERVER
set /p SERVER="What Application Server (1: Wildfly; 2: JBoss): "
if %SERVER% == 1 (
   set DST=%WILDFLY_DIR%
   set SERVICE=%SERVICE_WILDFLY%
) else if %SERVER% == 2 (
   set DST=%JBOSS_DIR%
   set SERVICE=%SERVICE_JBOSS%
) else (
   echo Unrecognized Server: %SERVER%
   goto :SEL_SERVER
)
goto :SEL_VERSION

:SEL_VERSION
set /p VERSION="What Version: "
IF /I NOT EXIST %EAR_DIR%\%VERSION% (
   ECHO Unrecognized Version: %VERSION%
   goto :SEL_VERSION
) else (
   set SRC=%EAR_DIR%\%VERSION%
   goto :DO_DEPLOY
)

:DO_DEPLOY
for /F "tokens=3 delims=: " %%H in ('sc query %SERVICE_WILDFLY% ^| findstr "        STATE"') do (
   if /I "%%H" == "RUNNING" (
     set /p STOP_WILDFLY="Wildfly 10 Service is running, stop it now? (Y/N) "
     if /I "%STOP_WILDFLY%" == "Y" (
         net stop %SERVICE_WILDFLY%
     )
   )
)
for /F "tokens=3 delims=: " %%G in ('sc query %SERVICE_JBOSS% ^| findstr "        STATE"') do (
   if /I "%%G" == "RUNNING" (
     set /p STOP_JBOSS="JBoss 6.1 Service is running, stop it now? (Y/N) "
     if /I "%STOP_JBOSS%" == "Y" (
         net stop %SERVICE_JBOSS%
     )
   )
)
echo Deleting existing EAR file...
FORFILES /p %DST% /m MyApplication*.* /c "cmd /c DEL @file"

@echo on
ROBOCOPY %SRC% %DST% MyApplication*.ear
@echo off
goto :START_SERVICE

:START_SERVICE
set /p START="Start Service Now? (Y/N) "

IF /I "%START%" == "Y" (
   net start "%SERVICE%"
)
goto :SEL_SERVER
```

The specific portion I am having a problem with is this:

```
for /F "tokens=3 delims=: " %%H in ('sc query %SERVICE_WILDFLY% ^| findstr "        STATE"') do (
   if /I "%%H" == "RUNNING" (
     set /p STOP_WILDFLY="Wildfly 10 Service is running, stop it now? (Y/N) "
     if /I "%STOP_WILDFLY%" == "Y" (
         net stop %SERVICE_WILDFLY%
     )
   )
)
for /F "tokens=3 delims=: " %%G in ('sc query %SERVICE_JBOSS% ^| findstr "        STATE"') do (
   if /I "%%G" == "RUNNING" (
     set /p STOP_JBOSS="JBoss 6.1 Service is running, stop it now? (Y/N) "
     if /I "%STOP_JBOSS%" == "Y" (
         net stop %SERVICE_JBOSS%
     )
   )
)
```

This is the output when the problem occurs:

```
What Application Server (1: Wildfly; 2: JBoss): 1
What Version: 2018.1.1
Wildfly 10 Service is running, stop it now? (Y/N) y
Deleting existing EAR file...

The rest removed for brevity....
```

When it works the output will look like this:

```
What Application Server (1: Wildfly; 2: JBoss): 1
What Version: 2018.2.1
Wildfly 10 Service is running, stop it now? (Y/N) y
The WildflyServiceName service is stopping...
The WildflyServiceName service was stopped successfully.

Deleting existing EAR file...

the rest removed for brevity....
```

I made sure to check for case sensitivity, and so it should accept y or Y.  It randomly just skips this step and goes straight on to deleting existing EAR files.  I have not been able to figure out why.

Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this?

----EDIT----

As Michael Heath indicated in the answer below, this is a delayed expansion problem.  I was able to resolve the problem by modifying the problem section of the batch file as follows:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /F "tokens=3 delims=: " %%H in ('sc query %SERVICE_WILDFLY% ^| findstr "        STATE"') do (
   if /I "%%H" == "RUNNING" (
     set /p STOP_WILDFLY="Wildfly 10 Service is running, stop it now? (Y/N) "
     if /I "!STOP_WILDFLY!" == "Y" (
         net stop %SERVICE_WILDFLY%
     )
   )
)
for /F "tokens=3 delims=: " %%G in ('sc query %SERVICE_JBOSS% ^| findstr "        STATE"') do (
   if /I "%%G" == "RUNNING" (
     set /p STOP_JBOSS="JBoss 6.1 Service is running, stop it now? (Y/N) "
     if /I "!STOP_JBOSS!" == "Y" (
         net stop %SERVICE_JBOSS%
     )
   )
)
endlocal
```

Comment: You also have a delayed expansion problem. Search for that with the [batch-file] tag and you will find the answer to that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using `setlocal` and thus the variables are not
local to the script.

The only way I see to stop a service is if you restart
the script in the same CMD session.

As Squashman commented, not using "*delayed expansion*" is
an issue.
You may see this if you run the script with `echo on` and
may see `"%STOP_WILDFLY%" == "Y"` evaluate to `"" == "Y"`
even though you type in some text.

Here is an example code block in `test.cmd`. A code block
is CMD parsing from an opening `(` to a closing `)`.
More than 1 set of `()` can exist in a line i.e.
`if ""=="" (...) else (...)` which could span multiple
literal lines in the script.

```
(
    set /p "reply=prompt [y|n]: "
    echo "%reply%"
)
```

CMD will parse that block of code and interpret like 1 line
and `%reply%` will be evaluated before you get to answer
the input prompt.

Run `test.cmd` twice and you may see:

```
C:\> test.cmd

C:\> (
set /p "reply=prompt [y|n]: "
 echo ""
)
prompt [y|n]: y
""

C:\> test.cmd

C:\> (
set /p "reply=prompt [y|n]: "
 echo "y"
)
prompt [y|n]: y
"y"
```

So now you may know why it sometimes works and sometimes does not work.

Use `setlocal` in the script unless you want to retain variables
after execution of the script in the same CMD session. Type
`setlocal /?` at a CMD prompt for more help.

Research "*delayed expansion*" by typing `set /?` at a CMD prompt.

Answer (score 0):

You are not waiting for the service to stop. You need to loop until the service status is stopped. [See my previous answer to a very similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47259350/windows-batch-file-eq-was-unexpected-at-this-time/47260287#47260287). Look for `:StoppedWait`.